# blogger / blogspot (guestAuth): how to get overriding warning page code

Tags: python, bash, blogger, blogspot

Using a browser and connecting to some blogger/blogspot site you can get a content warning.
Like this one:
http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html ("original page")
This content warning page overides the content page and displays a button for warning acknowledgment.
The acknoledgement button code is: 
http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html?guestAuth='SOME VERY LONG ID' ("warning content page")
The "SOME VERY LONG ID" is generated each time. Maybe this uses cookies ?
This works within a browser.

But I'm using a headless linux with bash and python scripts.
I need to display the html code of the content page.
But I need to acknowledge the warning first.
So I'm wondering if I access the "warning content page" first, then I should be able to access the content page.

But from the code I wrote I'm not able to display the warning page code. I have a somewhat extract of the content page.
I'm not able to grab that warning page code (tried with python and wget).

Here is my python script:

```
import os, sys, urllib, httplib2, validators, time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()

status, response = http.request(url)

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')):
    print link['src']
```

Is there a way from a script (python, bash...) to retrieve the link of the "warning content page" ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes.From received page retrieve the link to iframe. Fetch the content of iframe and there you can find the link with authGuest.

Comment: thank you.
Actually it's <iframe src="https://www.blogger.com/blogin.g?blogspotURL=http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.fr/2015/12/busy-as.html" and this displays the warning page.